# Add a graphic to an existing PictureBox

Tags: c#, graphics, picturebox

I've created a PictureBox in my programm. I've made some background lines on it when starting the program and after reading data from a file I would like to add a curve the this existing

```
namespace Program
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        Bitmap SPD_bmp = new Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height); //background graphic
        using (Graphics SPDCurve = Graphics.FromImage(SPD_bmp))
        {
            SPDCurve.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.LightGray), 0, 0, 0, 50);
            SPDCurve.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.LightGray), 10, 0, 10, 50);
            //... the rest of lines
                
        }
        PictureBox1.Image = SPD_bmp;
    }
            
            
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this part reads data from a file and should generate a curve 
        //from these data and add this curve to the exsiting PictureBox1
                
        //trying to add the curve to exsiting PictureBox1:
        Bitmap SPD_bmp = new Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height);
        using (Graphics SPDCurve = Graphics.FromImage(SPD_bmp))
        {
        //creating and adding the curve to the PictureBox1
        }
        PictureBox1.Image = SPD_bmp;
    }

}
```

but the code in buttonClick1 erases me the already existing background lines.

I'm duing something wrongly. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tag your language.

Comment: Sorry, It's C#.